# Hard to determine what type of off topic this question is

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, close-reasons, old-posts

I guess a custom reason could be used, such as "Not programming related" or something similar, but I am at a loss what is best for situations such as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/384164/1026459) (which I stumbled on as a result of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19824732/software-engineering-major-in-computer-science-vs-software-engineering-in-inform). It is old, and I realize that questions right when the site started were a little more open (since the whole exchange wasn't present then).

Should it even be closed because of that? I am not sure. What should happen to older posts like these?

Comment: VTCed that with a custom reason, but 'primarily opinion based' would also fit.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - I voted as well. I guess I was just on the fence and wanted some confirmation.

Comment: And... it is closed.

Comment: The meta effect at work.

Comment: Side question: Would it be on-topic for Programmers? Or is [Academia](http://academia.stackexchange.com/) the correct choice for this question? (Didn't even know Academia existed until I just googled)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although now deleted, both questions were about comparing computer science to computer engineering. The consensus was that they were off topic because they "not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the help center." with a custom message and were consequently deleted when closed.